# My center header is not centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, fancyhdr

I have the following code for my footer:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{My very important and long title that is not being centered as I would like to \newline Very Myself}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
```

but it is not centered:

[image]

How can I center it? I am using `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}`

Comment: Looks centered to me... Do you mean to have it be more... 'together'?

Comment: @SeanAllred Difference between start of the title and left page edge: 3cm; between right page edge and end of the title : 4cm

Comment: Can you add a complete minimal example?  Also, can you add the `showframe` option to the `geometry` package?  It will draw lines that make the difference more evident.

Comment: A MWE would help here. In particular, it would have told us which document class you're using and whether you're using `oneside` or `twoside`.

Comment: I have managed to do it by adding `\vfill` to the title like so : `\chead{\vfill My very important and long title that is not being centered as I would like to \newline Very Myself\vfill}`

Comment: Are you loading [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) at all? If so, *after* or *before* loading [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)?

Comment: @Werner I am loading `geometry` before `fancyhdr`.

Answer (score 6):

Use `\\` and not `\newline`. The behavior is easily reproducible:

```
\fbox{\parbox{5cm}{\centering A centered\\ text}}

\medskip

\fbox{\parbox{5cm}{\centering A centered\newline text}}
```

gives

[image]

Here's the code for you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\chead{%
  My very important and long title that is not being centered as I would like to \\ Very Myself
}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{24pt}
\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The command `\\` changes its meaning when in a `\centering` context, which is in force in `\chead`, whilst `\newline` doesn't.

Comment: What is the difference between `\\ ` and `\vfill` that I have used?

Comment: @Patryk `\vfill` is surely the wrong thing to use; the fact that it *appears* to work is purely incidental.

Answer (score 4):

Set the header inside a `tabular`, as line-breaking (using `\newline`) does not work as expected inside the header boxes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\chead{\begin{tabular}{c}
  My very important and long title that is not being centered as I would like to \\ Very Myself
\end{tabular}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{24pt}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```